# $F(x) := (n- 1)x-\frac{ (n- 1)n}{2}$ for $x \in [n- 1, n), n \in \Bbb N$ using this result to evaluate $\int_a^b[x]dx.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $F(x)$ be defined for $x \geq 0$ by $F(x) := (n- 1)x- (n- 1)n/2$ for $x \in [n- 1, n), n \in \Bbb N$. Show that $F$ is continuous and evaluate $F'(x)$ at points where this derivative exists and using  this result to evaluate $\int_a^b[x]dx.$

Here $F(x)$ is continuous and $F'(x) = (n- 1),\  x \in [n- 1, n), n \in \Bbb N$ and this gives us the $[x]$ or the the greatest integer function.

But how to use the function and fundamental theorem to evaluate $\int_a^b[x]dx$?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$F_n(x) := (n- 1)x- (n- 1)n/2
$.
To show that
$F$ is continuous,
we have to show that
$F_n(n)
=F_{n+1}(n)
$.
But
$F_n(n)
=(n-1)n-n(n-1)/2
=n(n-1)/2
$
(since $F_n$ is continuous,
bounded on$[n-1, n)$,
and defined at $x=n$,
$\lim_{x \to n} F_n(x)
= F_n(n)$)
and
$F_{n+1}(n)
=(n)n-(n+1)(n)/2
=(2n^2-n^2-n)/2
=(n^2-n)/2
=F_n(n)
$.

Then,
$\int_a^b [x] dx
=\int_a^b F'(x) dx
=F(x)\big|_a^b
= F(b)-F(a)
$.